# Difference between Redirect Class and Router.navigate method in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

What is the difference between Redirect class and Router.navigate method?

I know that when I use Router, I will use @inject to the constructor and then use the navigate method. when use Redirect, I create an instance of Redirect - `new Redirect('myRouteName')`.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` class object is a special object that tells the `Router` to stop what it's doing and start the whole process over again using the new instruction.

The `router.navigate` method will begin an entirely new navigate once the current navigation is complete.

For example, lets say you return a `Redirect` from a `canActivate` method. This will prevent the `activate` method from being called. If you had called `router.navigate` instead, `activate` would be called.

Comment: Is there any difference between them if I use them in the `config.addPipelineStep()`?